# PhD Application

Tags: phd, advisor

I was contacting a potential supervisor for a PhD program. I was happy to get a reply from the Professor stating that my proposed research interests is in line with his research activities.

The Professor then asked me to look for other financial sources since he currently doesn't have the funding to support my research. As per his guidance I have successfully submitted my application to the suggested scholarship.

Now, I would like to know whether I should update the Professor about my submitted application and also share my application details??

Comment: There is nothing wrong in it. Especially if you are aware of admission procedure and you know that professor plays important role in admission process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should. This is common courtesy actually.